# Embedding all the external resources of an HTML page into a single file using javascript in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, inline-images

As you all know, external resources, like images, can be embedded into the html file using base64 encoding:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />
```

I'm looking for **a pure browser-based javascript** way to traverse an html page and embed all the external resources into the file so when I say `$("html").html()`, it returns all the page's contents. Even including its external resources.

Just so it makes sense, I'm trying to download web pages into single files using a headless browser on my server.

Comment: If you're using JS, why encode the images?

Comment: Because JS can easily traverse all the html elements. Otherwise I'll need a parser to read and turn the tags into DOM objects before I can query them for external resources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are tools out there to do that.
Examples:

- https://github.com/remy/inliner
- https://github.com/jgallen23/grunt-inline-css
- https://github.com/ceee/grunt-datauri

While there are benefits to this approach, remember that a page visited more than once, or site with multiple pages with same JS/CSS files will enjoy client (browser) side caching.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that by javascript I mean a browser-based one. I'm looking for a non-NodeJs solution.

Comment: the tools I suggest are running as one time on the server, to generate the client side js/css. There are not server side solution, just tools.

Comment: I know, but I'm looking for a solution that uses a web browser. I find this much more stable solution than NodeJs as a web browser's parser is much more powerful than any other. I intend to use PhantomJs with javascript.

Comment: Does anyone have had any experience with those tools and could recomend one?

Answer (score 1):

#### Browser extensions

There are [Save Page WE extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof/related):

- Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/
- Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof/related

This extension can scroll or zoom out the page in order to allow  fetching lazy-loading resources before saving.

#### Command line tools

There is also the [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner) npm module which exposes the `inliner` command line utility — it works with some URLs but throws an error with others. It pipes the output to stdout and therefore needs to be used like e.g. `inliner https://http.cat > cats.html`.

It can be installed with (assuming you have nodejs+npm):

```
npm install -g inliner
```