# Inlining external HTML resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, command

I'm wondering if there's an existing (Linux) tool/command to make a HTML file more "standalone" by automatically inlining third-party resources (JS and CSS).

I'm using [a tool](https://asv.readthedocs.io/en/latest) which generates HTML reports, and these reports contain references to third-party CSS (Bootstrap) and JS (jQuery). These resources don't work if the page is accessed via `file://`, due to security restrictions. They work when served from a HTTP server, but that's obviously not ideal when the files are local to the machine.

So far I've created a script to find/replace these particular URLs with data URIs of their content. This works for now, but is a maintenance burden due to everything being hard-coded.

Is there a more reliable/standard way to achieve a similar effect? I can think of a few ways to do this: creating data URIs (like my script), writing the content into the style/script elements, or replacing the URLs with relative paths to local copies. Any of these would be fine. Ideally I could just do something like:

```
$ inlineHtmlResources < existingFile.html > standloneVersion.html
```

Comment: "save page as" works well

Comment: @dandavis I presume you mean for Firefox or similar? I think this would require firing up a HTTP server temporarily too, since the URLs don't work. Can "save as" be triggered via a script, or would I have to rely on something like `xdotool`? The latter wouldn't work headless though, so I'd need XVFB or equivalent :(

Comment: there's two inlining "standards"; mshtml and base64 resource urls, using dataURLs or email-like packaging. mshtml works pretty well since chrome added support a few years back. You could also write a small JS that simply spiders the urls (finding all the @href+@src), using ajax to fetch the content as a blob, then using FileReader to turn the blob into a dataURL which replaces the attrib's URL. after, `document.documentElement.outerHTML` should be a complete representation of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @WillCain was helpful, but as a plugin for a plugin for a system I've never used (webpack) it seemed a little overkill for me.

I ended up writing a simple Python script to do it instead http://chriswarbo.net/git/html-inliner/git

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at webpack, which the following question addresses for essentially the same use case you suggest:

[How to bundle html, js and css in one html file with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866228/how-to-bundle-html-js-and-css-in-one-html-file-with-webpack)

The above answer cites specifically this plugin:
https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin

There are many alternatives; others are included in this question:
[Embedding all the external resources of an HTML page into a single file using javascript in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595416/embedding-all-the-external-resources-of-an-html-page-into-a-single-file-using-ja)