# Embedding the local external resources of an HTML page into a single HTML file

Tags: html, image, embed, inline-images

I am looking for a working way to automatically embed all local external images (i.e. images on the local file system) which are referenced in the HTML file like

```
<img data-src="img/my_image.png" />
```

Obviously this will probably involve the `data` keyword in HTML. Regarding this problem I have read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595416/embedding-all-the-external-resources-of-an-html-page-into-a-single-file-using-ja) and I tried the suggested tool [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner), but the tool seems to have trouble with external local resources like above.

Are there other proven ways/tools for this job which *do* handle above mentioned case, preferable currently maintained and maybe even in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the attribute `data-src`. It has in this particular situation a similar meaning to `src`, but only because the HTML file uses a JavaScript library ([reveal.js – The HTML Presentation Framework](https://revealjs.com/#/)) which interprets this attribute similar to the standard `src` attribute.

However the link embedding tool ([*inliner*](https://github.com/remy/inliner) here) does not know about this! So the solution is to **replace `data-src` with `src`.** This can be done e.g. with a `sed` script. Then *inliner* converts the file correctly.